# MonoDevelop のキー配置を Eclipse に合わせる方法

Tags: c#, eclipse

Unityの開発でMonoDevelopを使用していますが、
Eclipseを使い慣れているため、キー配置をEclipseに合わせたいです。
キー配置を一つ一つ見比べるのではなくて、すぐにEclipseに合わせる方法などないでしょうか？